# Communication with Windows Phone Through Windows 10 PC

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I wanna develop an application that would access messages, photos and other data from Windows phone through PC, an application much like Nokia PC suite. Can anybody suggest me the articles and APIs on this kind of development. My development platform would be C#.Net and OS would be Windows 10. The devices I would communicate through my PC would be Windows phone 8.1 and after launch of Windows 10 mobile I have plans to transform my app for that one.

Comment: Sorry there are no apis to access the phone through usb.  Typically files are transferred with a cloud service such as onedrive between PC and phone

Comment: So it means I have to go for app-to-app communication over WiFi or Bluetooth. Will it work with USB connection?